# Request for example server side generated JSON for HPP integration

Tags: realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I'm trying to use a full page redirect with a direct integration and if I'm reading the documentation correctly I believe I should be able to generate the server side JSON to pass into RealexHpp.redirect. I know the code to generate this JSON is shared in a number of languages, but is the raw JSON output shared anywhere? I ask as the language I'm writing in isn't one of the ones covered, so I'm trying to make sure I get the output format correct.

I've tried re-creating the JSON structure based on what I believe the Java code displayed should output, but I'm obviously doing something wrong as its not working, would be really useful if I had some raw JSON to compare it against to make sure I'm getting the structure right.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw JSON examples are not available, but we do have HTML POST examples (https://developer.globalpay.com/hpp/card-payments). You can build a JSON based on these.

This is how the JSON should look like: {"MERCHANT_ID":"MerchantId","ACCOUNT":"internet","ORDER_ID":"N6qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g","AMOUNT":"1999","CURRENCY":"EUR","TIMESTAMP":"20221121100715","AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG":"1","SHIPPING_CODE":"50001|Apartment 825","SHIPPING_CO":"US","HPP_SHIPPING_STREET1":"Apartment 825","HPP_SHIPPING_STREET2":"Complex 741","HPP_SHIPPING_STREET3":"House 963","HPP_SHIPPING_CITY":"Chicago","HPP_SHIPPING_STATE":"IL","HPP_SHIPPING_POSTALCODE":"50001","HPP_SHIPPING_COUNTRY":"840","BILLING_CODE":"59|123","BILLING_CO":"GB","HPP_BILLING_STREET1":"Flat 123","HPP_BILLING_STREET2":"House 456","HPP_BILLING_STREET3":"Unit 4","HPP_BILLING_CITY":"Halifax","HPP_BILLING_POSTALCODE":"W5 9HR","HPP_BILLING_COUNTRY":"826","HPP_CUSTOMER_EMAIL":"james.mason@example.com","HPP_CUSTOMER_PHONENUMBER_MOBILE":"44|07123456789","HPP_PHONE":"44|07123456789","HPP_ADDRESS_MATCH_INDICATOR":"FALSE","HPP_VERSION":"2","SHA1HASH":"308bb8dfbbfcc67c28d602d988ab104c3b08d012"}

Comment: Thank you for sharing the example JSON, this has helped me a lot.